# Command key inconsistently works in Remote Desktop

Tags: remote-desktop

How do I use spotlight via ⌘ + spacebar in the remote computer? It works sometimes but not all the time.

Using Apple's Remote Desktop to connect to a mac mini, I often open spotlight via ⌘ + spacebar. It sometimes works and sometimes opens my main computer's spotlight. Changing the focus, the active window, and making the remote full screen all don't change anything. Closing and re-opening remote desktop has a chance of making it work.

The behavior is the same for ⌘ + tab